# Isometries of the sphere - $S^2$.

Tags: geometry, spherical-geometry, noneuclidean-geometry

Is a translation in $S^2$ an isometry?

Also with regards to a reflection in a plane, why does the plane have to contain the centre of the sphere for the reflection to be an isometry?

Comment: What do you mean by "a translation in S^2"?

Comment: The fact you seem to be missing is that an isometry of $S^2$ must send $S^2$ *to itself*.

Comment: Oh yes of course. This answers both questions, thanks!